# flatten function works with dictionary but not a list containing dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, flatten

I have my python script which works perfectly when flattening a dictionary, however, when it's a list of dictionaries it will not work due to a list not having the method - `items()`.

```
def flatten(dictionary, p_key=None, parent_key=False, separator='.'):
    items = []
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if parent_key:
            new_key = f"{str(p_key)}{separator}{key}"
        else:
            new_key = p_key if p_key else key
        if isinstance(value, mm):
            items.extend(flatten(
                dictionary=value,
                p_key=new_key,
                parent_key=True,
                separator=separator).items())
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for k, v in enumerate(value):
                items.extend(flatten(
                    dictionary={str(k): v},
                    p_key=new_key,
                    parent_key=False,
                    separator=separator).items())
        else:
            items.append((new_key, value))
    return dict(items)


d = [{ 
    "_id" : 1, 
    "labelId" : [
        6422
    ], 
    "levels" : [
        {
            "active" : "true", 
            "level" : 3, 
            "actions" : [
                {
                    "isActive" : "true"
                }]
        }]
}]


x = flatten(d)

x = json_normalize(x)

print(x)
```

If I remove the surrounding square brackets it will accurately print the correct flattened dataframe.

Is there a way to update this code so that it can essentially go inside that list and then start flattening the dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add code to loop through the list at the begining of the function. The below code would work for the scenario that you mentioned.

```
    items = []
    if isinstance(dictionary, list):
        for listval in dictionary:
            items.extend(flatten(listval).items())
    else:    
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
```

Comment: would this only work if there's one dictionary in the list? e.g what if there are two dictionaries within the lists

Comment: it seems to just be retrieving the last record in the dictionary rather than printing everything, I think it's because you cant append a dictionary to another dictionary when there are duplicate keys, it has to be unique